# Help with text formatting

Tags: text-formatting

I need help with bash scripting. Below is my input:

```
Grp: MG1
user1 
user2 
user3 
Grp: MG2
user7 
user1 
user9 
user6 
user2
```

The result should look like:

```
Reporting MG1
MG1,user1 
MG1,user2 
MG1,user3 
Reporting MG2
MG2,user7 
MG2,user1 
MG2,user9 
MG2,user6 
MG2,user2
```

I tried `sed -n '/cn:/,/cn:/p' file`, but it didn't do what I want.

Comment: Hi, what is the relevance of string `cn:` used in your sed with the sample input you provided?

Comment: You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).

Answer (score 3):

with `awk` which is the right tool for text-formatting:

```
awk '/^Grp:/ { OFS=" "; $1= "Reporting"; mg=$2; print; next} 
             { OFS=","; print mg, $0}' infile
```

Comment: Very nice!  The OP originally had blank lines in the input; I'm not sure if that was intentional or just poor formatting.  It might be worth tweaking this a little to handle blank lines in the input just in case.

Comment: I think so and that was formatting issue. if not, pre-pending `NF` to the second line would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
$ cat script.sed
/^Grp: / {                              ;# A "Grp: " line
        s///                            ;# Remove "Grp: "
        h                               ;# Save in hold space
        s/^/Reporting /p                ;# Insert "Reporting " at start, print
        d                               ;# Delete, start next cycle
}

# Any other line:
G                               ;# Append the hold space
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/         ;# Swap strings around \n, insert comma
```

```
$ sed -f script.sed file
Reporting MG1
MG1,user1
MG1,user2
MG1,user3
Reporting MG2
MG2,user7
MG2,user1
MG2,user9
MG2,user6
MG2,user2
```

As a "one-liner":

```
sed -e '/^Grp: /{s///;h;s/^/Reporting /p;d;}' \
    -e 'G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/' file
```

A similar approach to the above with `awk`:

```
awk '/^Grp: / { sub("^Grp: ", ""); group = $0; print "Reporting " $0; next }
              { print group "," $0 }' file
```

Both the `sed` and `awk` variations in this answer (as well as the `sh` variant at the end below) would cope with spaces in the data, either in the `MG` strings or in the `user` strings:

```
$ cat file
Grp: some group ID
line 1
the other line
```

```
$ sed -e '/^Grp: /{s///;h;s/^/Reporting /p;d;}' -e 'G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2,\1/' file
Reporting some group ID
some group ID,line 1
some group ID,the other line
```

---

Just as a fun exercise, using `/bin/sh`:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
        case $line in
                'Grp: '*)
                        group=${line#Grp: }
                        printf 'Reporting %s\n' "$group"
                        ;;
                *)
                        printf '%s,%s\n' "$group" "$line"
        esac
done
```

Run with

```
sh script.sh <file
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample input above, you can use this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

group=""

while read line; do
    if [[ "${line}" =~ ^Grp:* ]]; then
        group="$(echo "${line}" | awk '{ print $2 }')"
        echo "Reporting ${group}"
    elif [[ "${line}" == "" ]]; then
        echo
    else
        echo "${group},${line}"
    fi
done
```

For example:

```
$ cat input
Grp: MG1
user1
user2
user3
Grp: MG2
user7
user1
user9
user6
user2
$

$ ./ex.sh < input
Reporting MG1
MG1,user1
MG1,user2
MG1,user3
Reporting MG2
MG2,user7
MG2,user1
MG2,user9
MG2,user6
MG2,user2
$
```

The script runs a loop that reads a line of text.  If the line begins with `Grp:`, then it saves the second whitespace delimited token as the `group`.  If the line is blank, then it prints a blank line.  Otherwise, it prints the last-read group, followed by a comma, followed by the content of the line.